# How long updating by anaconda navigator updater?

Tags: python, anaconda, updates

Now Anaconda is updating from 1.6.9 to 1.8.7 version by Anaconda Navigator Updater.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob8LG.png)
But it takes over 2 day2 and continueing yet now.
How long it need to update ? Maybe error ?

Comment: I've exactly the same problem, 10 hours, would be nice to know how this ended